# $E(n)\# \mathbb{CP}^2=2n\mathbb{CP}^2\# (10n-1)\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, kirby-diagram

How does one prove the following statement : $$E(n)\# \mathbb{CP}^2=2n\mathbb{CP}^2\# (10n-1)\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$$
Here $E(n)$ denotes the $n$-th elliptic surface formed by fiber summing $E(1)$ $n$ times. I tried to do induction on $n$, so for $n=1$, I saw that the definition of the elliptic surface $E(1)$ is $\mathbb{CP}^2\# 9\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ so it holds in that case. But for $n=2$ I am getting $$E(2)\# \mathbb{CP}^2=3\mathbb{CP}^2\# 18\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$$ but the statement claims it should be $4\mathbb{CP}^2\# 19\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$. How does one show the numbers should match? Will this require Kirby diagrams? I'm not very expert in Kirby diagrams, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $E(n)$ is not the connected sum of $n$ copies of $E(1)$, but rather the fiber sum of $n$ copies of $E(1)$. It is homeomorphic to $(2n-1)\mathbb{CP}^2\#(10n-1)\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$. Are you trying to show that $E(n)\#\mathbb{CP}^2$ is homeomorphic to $2n\mathbb{CP}^2\#(10n-1)\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ or diffeomorphic to it?

Comment: I think it must be diffeomorphic to it. Then it is homeomorphic also. Also what is the difference between fiber sum and connected sum? Sorry for my error.

Comment: In a fiber sum, you take out a neighbourhood of a smooth fiber in both manifolds (homeomorphic to $T^2\times D^2$), leaving you with two manifolds with boundary $T^3$. Using a fiber-preserving orientation-reversing diffeomorphism of the boundaries, you glue together two manifolds to obtain a new elliptic surface. I believe you need to use Kirby calculus to prove that $E(n)\#\mathbb{CP}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $2n\mathbb{CP}^2\#(10n-1)\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$.

Comment: Thank you Michael Albanese, I have corrected my mistake. So how would I solve this problem with Kirby Calculus?

Comment: This is Exercise 8.3.4 (d) of Gompf and Stipsicz's *4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus*. The exercise comes with a hint which indicates how to manipulate a Kirby diagram for $E(n)\#\mathbb{CP}^2$.